# PostgreSQL order of WHERE "table"."column" IN query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

In PostgreSQL, does this query

```
SELECT "table".* FROM "table" WHERE "table"."column" IN (1, 5, 3)
```

always return the results in the `1, 5, 3` order or is it ambiguous?
If it's ambiguous, how do I properly assure the results are in the order `1, 5, 3`?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: @bernie - If this is a duplicate, please provide a link to what it is a duplicate of.

Comment: Sorry. Agreed. Don't have time at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like the following to your select statement

```
order by CASE WHEN "column"=1 THEN 1
              WHEN "column"=2 THEN 2
              ELSE 3
       END
```

if you have many more than three values it may be easier to make a lookup table and join to that in you query

Comment: I have about 20 values, but I was able to implement this solution nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The WHERE clause will not order the results in any way, it will just select matching records, in whatever order the database index finds them in.

You'll have to add an order by clause.

Answer (score 2):

False orders before true

```
SELECT "table".*
FROM "table"
WHERE "table"."column" IN (1, 5, 3)
order by
    "column" != 1,
    "column" != 5,
    "column" != 3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use "IN" in a select statement Postgre just return the matching rows against that range of values. It's not ambiguous in any way but if you need to order the results you need to explicitly add ORDER BY "column1,column2..."

Answer (score 1):

A *set* knows *no order* per se. A `SELECT` query needs `ORDER BY` to return ordered rows.

Other answers have suggested `CASE` statements or boolean expressions in your `ORDER BY`, but that's far from elegant and rather *inefficient* with big tables. I suggest to use an **array** or a **comma-separated string** instead of a set for your query.

For a given table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (col int);
```

Using an *array* it can work like this:

```
SELECT col
FROM   tbl
JOIN  (
   SELECT col, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM   unnest('{1,5,3}'::int[]) AS col
   ) u USING (col)
ORDER  BY rn;
```

Returns all rows found *in the sequence of the input array*:

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6dcf6/1)

For more details and future-proof code consider this closely related question:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number)

Or the corresponding question on dba.SE:
[How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-do-i-preserve-the-order-of-the-original-elements-in-an-unnested-array)